# Error Deploying MobileFirst Server Configuration

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

In the process of upgrading a remote MobileFirst Server to version 7.0 (from version 6.2), and I've run into an issue when attempting to use the Server Configuration Tool to redeploy.

Here's the only apparent error I'm seeing, unsure what other information you may need to help diagnose this:

```
Buildfile: /home/worklight/.worklight/server-configuration-tool/Configuration_MobileFirst_7/MobileFirst_7.xml

adminstall:
[installworklightadmin] Logging output of task <installWorklightAdmin> to file /home/worklight/.mobilefirst_platform_server/configuration-logs/installWorklightAdmin_2015_06_15_14_57_11.log
[installworklightadmin] WARNING:
[installworklightadmin] The value of the MySQL system variable innodb_log_file_size is 5,242,880 (5 MB). The recommended limit is 250 MB.
[installworklightadmin] For more information, see the MySQL Reference Manual, sections "Server System Variables" and "InnoDB Configuration" for details.
[installworklightadmin] http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html
[installworklightadmin] http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-configuration.html

BUILD FAILED
/home/worklight/.worklight/server-configuration-tool/Configuration_MobileFirst_7/MobileFirst_7.xml:71: The element <installWorklightAdmin>, <jmx libertyAdminUser=".." libertyAdminPassword="..."/> is missing. A default user cannot be created for this server.

Total time: 2 seconds
```

I don't actually have the "Create a default user" options selected in the last pane, but that error appears either way.

Also seeing this same error if I attempt to create a new server configuration entirely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About the error message:

```
/home/worklight/.worklight/server-configuration-tool/Configuration_MobileFirst_7‌​/MobileFirst_7.xml:71: The element ,  is missing. A default user cannot be created for this server.
```

This happens if your Liberty is configured for LDAP. In that case, the server configuration tool is not able to add a user (it can add users if Liberty has a basic registry). This also prevents the server configuration tool from performing an install because it needs to create a user for JMX (a Liberty Adminstrator).

The workarounds are:

- Export your 6.2 configuration as ant files (In the Server Configuration Tool, menu File/Export Configuration as ant files) and run the files manually as described here https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.upgrade.doc/devenv/c_upgrade_to_srvr_upgrading_wl_runtime_TOP.html . The ant targets you need to run (to upgrade the databases of perform a 'minimal update' don't need to create users and should work with a Liberty configured with LDAP)
- If you can't export the 6.2, files, you need to create your own ant files (for example using the sample configurations in /WorklightServer/configuration-samples) and add the attributes indicated in the error message. The reference manual of ant tasks is here:  https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.reference.doc/devref/r_ant_tasks_installwladmin_reference.html

Comment: Seems like the LDAP configuration was the issue.  Thanks for the quick reply!

Answer (score 0):

This warning is about a parameter in mySQL that needs to be increased to avoid errors later at runtime. It's a warning and should (in theory) not be related to an error in the Server Configuration Tool. What is the problem with the Server Configuration Tool ?

```
[installworklightadmin] The value of the MySQL system variable innodb_log_file_size is 5,242,880 (5 MB). The recommended limit is 250 MB.
[installworklightadmin] For more information, see the MySQL Reference Manual, sections "Server System Variables" and "InnoDB Configuration" for details.
[installworklightadmin] http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html
[installworklightadmin] http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-configuration.html
```

Comment: I now see the error: /home/worklight/.worklight/server-configuration-tool/Configuration_MobileFirst_7/MobileFirst_7.xml:71: The element <installWorklightAdmin>, <jmx libertyAdminUser=".." libertyAdminPassword="..."/> is missing. A default user cannot be created for this server.